# How to clear all Finder Alerts

Tags: macos, finder

I'm not sure why but I have a lot of Finder Alerts "Disk Not Ejected Properly."  So many that I'd probably spend all day clicking the little x to dismiss them.

[image]

Is there some way to dismiss them all at once?  I've searched and all I can find is how to dismiss all ordinary notification (I can't even access the notifications because it is covered by all of these alerts).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/325547/how-do-i-dismiss-many-multiples-of-the-disk-not-ejected-properly-notification